# Выделенный сервер и ОС Linux. Защита

Tags: linux, безопасность, администрирование, vps, защита

касаемо самого выделенного сервера и ОС Linux.
Какие могут быть подводные камни с ними? Как защитить выделенный сервер и ОС?

1)по поводу доступа неправомерного;

2)всяких там сканов портов, протоколы, потборов паролей и т.д.;

3)бреши-уязвимости ос\vps;

4)права доступа \ что закрыть там.

Comment: В первую очередь — досконально понимать, что вообще творится на сервере, и не забывать регулярно ставить обновления. Всё остальное автоматически выведется как следствие.

Comment: Не соглашусь, по моему мнению нужно ставить только обновления безопасности т.к. через обыч. обновления может и эксплойт новый быть.